# Example of isomorphism despite different orders?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is it possible to have an isomorphism between two groups even though they have different orders (specifically finite order)? How about an infinite order group and a finite order group? I'm asking because I've been led to believe it is true, and so I would like to see some examples (particularly constructed isomorphisms please).

---

**EDIT**

I am asking this specifically because as an exercise in a book I found, I am asked to show that Aut$(\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$. Now given that Aut$(\mathbb{Z})$ is the set of all automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$, I can immediately populate my mind with an infinite number of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$, and so the order of Aut$(\mathbb{Z})$ is infinite. However, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has an order of $2$, and so I can't possibly see how the two groups could be isomorphic.

Of course, I may be wrong with the order of Aut$(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Isomorphisms are possible only between groups of the same order, as they must be /bijective/ homomorphisms. A bijection can only be drawn between sets of the same cardinality.

However, there can be homomorphisms between groups of different order. For instance, $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ by $\overline{z} \mapsto \overline{z}$.

Edit: $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ does not have infinite order. You must have a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ that is both surjective and injective. The only two such maps are $z \mapsto z$ and $z \mapsto -z$. The proof of that is nontrivial but not so bad; see if you can do it.

If you don't believe me, shoot out something you believe to be an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ and we can determine why it must not be a homomorphism, injective, or surjective (or any of those) together.

Comment: Please see the edit. Yes, definitely homomorphisms.

Comment: Alright, what about the following map: $z\to z$, for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ except for 0 and 1. For 0 and 1, swap them. I can't see why this isn't bijective.

Comment: It may be bijective, but it must also be a *homomorphism*. Your example is not a homomorphism. Can you see why?

Comment: Oh my gosh I'm an idiot. I didn't really understand what that meant for groups, and now I do. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan No problem! That's what MSE is here for. In general, for **constructs** (that is, sets equipped with operation[s]) we concern ourselves with *morphisms,* maps which preserve the structure of the operation(s), and *isomorphisms* which are morphisms that are also bijections between the ground sets. A big part of understanding the constructs is understanding the structure-preserving maps between objects of the same kind.

Answer (score 2):

Isomorphisms are by definition homomorphisms that have a two sided inverse, of course if any function has a two sided inverse it must be a bijection. Hence isomorphisms are bijections, and hence can only exist between groups of the same order.

---

The number of automorphisms on $\mathbb Z$ is not infinite. This is because if you know what the image of $1$ is you can determine the whole automorphism, but $1$ must go to another generator of $\mathbb Z$.